# Issue with only data with the month September when converting Characters to Date

Tags: r, csv, date, formatting

I tried to convert a column called As_of_Dt3 using the following code:

```
library(zoo)

data <- read.csv("C:/Users/user23/Documents/R_Output/data.csv", header = TRUE)

data$As_of_Dt <- as.character(data$As_of_Dt)
data$As_of_Dt <- trimws(data$As_of_Dt)
data$As_of_Dt2 <- as.Date(as.yearmon(BBG$As_of_Dt))
data$As_of_Dt3 <- format(as.Date(data$As_of_Dt2), "%m/%d/%y")

#This is to count the number of NAs in the column As_of_Dt3
sum(is.na(data$As_of_Dt3))
```

A couple of notes about the code, I wanted to view each step in the code when I viewed it in excel to troubleshoot the issue. This is why As_of_Dt is separated into three different columns.

Here all possible values of As_of_Dt:

```
"Feb 2017" 
"March 2017"
"April 2017"
"May 2017"
"June 2017"
"July 2017"
"Aug 2017"
"Sept 2017"
"Oct 2017"
"Nov 2017"
"Dec 2017"   
"Jan 2018"
"Feb 2018"
"March 2018"
"April 2018"
"May 2018"
"June 2018"
"July 2018"
"Aug 2018"
"Sept 2018"
"Oct 2018"
"Nov 2018"   
"Dec 2018"
"Jan 2019"
"Feb 2019"
"March 2019"
"April 2019"
"May 2019"
"June 2019"
"July 2019"
"Aug 2019"
"Sept 2019"
"Oct 2019"   
"Nov 2019"
"Dec 2019"
"Jan 2020"
"Feb 2020"
"August 2019"
```

All of the NAs are when As_of_Dt is either "Sept 2017", "Sept 2018", or "Sept 2019"
How do I prevent NAs for the above values for As_of_Dt3? I'm also curious why it is happening too as the rest of the values for As_of_Dt3 aren't any different in terms of format of the original value.

Comment: Looks like `zoo::as.yearmon` doesn't recognize "Sept" and an abbreviation for September. If you change the "Sept" to "Sep" it would work: `zoo::as.yearmon("Sep 2017")`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, this is the exact code I used based on MrFlick's comments. This seemed to result in no NAs.

```
library(zoo)

data <- read.csv("C:/Users/user23/Documents/R_Output/data.csv", header = TRUE)

data$As_of_Dt <- as.character(data$As_of_Dt)
data$As_of_Dt <- trimws(data$As_of_Dt)

data$As_of_Dt[data$As_of_Dt== "Sept 2018"] <- "Sep 2018"
data$As_of_Dt[data$As_of_Dt== "Sept 2017"] <- "Sep 2017"
data$As_of_Dt[data$As_of_Dt== "Sept 2019"] <- "Sep 2019"

data$As_of_Dt2 <- as.Date(as.yearmon(BBG$As_of_Dt))
data$As_of_Dt3 <- format(as.Date(data$As_of_Dt2), "%m/%d/%y")

#This is to count the number of NAs in the column As_of_Dt3
sum(is.na(data$As_of_Dt3))
```

Thank you again MrFlick!